# Regex a^xb^y substitute

Tags: python, regex, substitution

I want to find a regex in python so that I can determine user entries that have the following shape.

**a^xb^y**

When such an entry within a string is found I want to flag it as spam.

a: can be any character

b: can be any character except for the character used in a

x >=2, y >=2

Examples:

- "this text is a ggeeeeeefff example" **should** match (ggeeeeeefff)
- "xxoxo maybe this will help" **should not** match
- "yyyyyyyyyee r u always so silly" **should** match (yyyyyyyyyee)

The code I tried:

```
string = "hello is abbbb aabbbbbcccddddddd...eefffggggggghhhhiiii,,,???jj"

reg1 = re.compile("(.)\1{1,}")
match = reg1.match(string)
print(match)
```

**OUT:**
`None`  However when I use re.sub it does substitute it.

```
string_sub = re.sub(r"(.)\1{1,}", r"\1", string)
print(string_sub)
```

**OUT:** `helo is ab abcd.efghi,?j`

This should **not** happen since, "hello" should remain "hello" and "abbb" should also remain "abbb". "aabbbbbcccddddddd...eefffggggggghhhhiiii,,,???jj" was converted correctly. Substituting is fine by me, since `len(string)` > `len(string_sub)` holds. And then I could use that to flag the string:

```
if(len(string_sub) < len(string)):
    print("String flagged as spam.")
else:
    print("String NOT flagged as spam.")
```

This unfortunately also does not work.

```
string_sub2 = re.sub(r"(.)\1{1,}(?!\1)(.)\1{1,}",r"\1\1", string)
```

Comment: That's a pretty awful spam filter. No one is allowed to talk about balloons, or raccoons, or spittoons, or committees...

Comment: Thats a good hint. But since every entry will be reviewed afterwards as well, it does make sense to use it. The reason behind is, that I am using a profanity model to predict if entries contain profanity. We also want to get rid of entries such as "aabb" which are pretty common unfortunately. So a regex-filter placed before the model should work. Also those topics don't really concern us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original regex should be working, but why are you using `\1` for both `{1,}`?

It should be like this `(.)\1{1,}(?!\1)(.)\2{1,}`, the problem is that it would also match numbers like `111222`, so I think it might be better to use `[A-Za-z]` or just `[a-z]` with the `i` flag.

Your regex also doesn't match a full word, I don't know if this is intentional.

You might be able to use:

1. To match full words that have this pattern

   - `\b([A-Za-z])\1{1,}(?!\1)([A-Za-z])\2{1,}\S*\b`
   - `\b\w+([A-Za-z])\1{1,}(?!\1)([A-Za-z])\2{1,}\S*\b`

   you could remove the `\S*` if you don't want it to match up to the first space.
2. If you just want to find it wherever it exists

   - `([A-Za-z])\1{1,}(?!\1)([A-Za-z])\2{1,}`

Comment: Usually I would want to capture all characters, but in the case of digits it makes sense to leave them out. So instead of [A-Za-z] -> [\D] should work fine for me. Thank you :)